# Login errors in .bashrc in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, bash, lightdm, bashrc

I just upgraded to 13.04, and suddenly I get xsession errors in my `.bashrc` on login. There is nothing wrong with the `.bashrc` file--I can source it from a terminal login, and after I get into the desktop it also sources fine. But during the desktop login there are errors in the following two sections:

```
PS1="\[\e[1;34m\]---\W---|\[\e[0m\] "
```

.xsession-errors says: `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 9: [: up: unexpected operator`

```
for i in {1..3} 
do
    export dc$i="bhawkins@dc-$i...edu"
done
```

.xsession-errors says: `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 79: bad identifier dc{1..3}`

The `.bashrc` file has not changed since upgrading, and of course there is no syntax error. Is there maybe something in 13.04 that is referencing `.bashrc` in a new way, using a different shell that doesn't understand basic bash?